# Foreign key filtering in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am currently looking for a way in PostgreSQL where I can, for a given table, limit the number of valid foreign keys
available by defining a condition.

So the scenario is like this

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4dbe279906dc881598b7e72093534ce7

A, B, C All represent different entities, and each specific entry is listed in the x_entry table.

The tables A, B, C all represents versions of a given entry,  an in what time span they are valid.

I want to ensure that
the table A always have foreign keys to B and C
where the condition `A.B.C == A.C` for the timespan A.

As seen here

[image]
The condition for `Ainit` for the range 2000-3000 is violated since, `binit` in the time range `2100-3000` has a foreign key to `cinot`
where ainit changes it foreign key from cinit to `cinat` violating the condition of `A.B.C == A.C`

But how do i set up such a conditional limit, that prevent a certain condition like this is not being violated for foreign keys. ?
and is it even possible?

Comment: `id BIGSERIAL REFERENCES C_entry(id),` <<-- this is nonsensical

Comment: Why does it not make sense, i am referencing another table id.

Comment: A foreign key *refers* to a PK (or some other unique key) in another table. That *could* be a (big)serial. The foreign key itself should not be a serial. (that would make it rather independent from the referred-to key)

Comment: @wildplasser either I am misunderstanding, but postgresql syntax state the the foreign key itself also need a type specified. It cannot be leaved unspecified.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/tutorial-fk.html

Comment: I think, what @wildplasser means, is that type should be BIGINT instead of BIGSERIAL

Comment: If you get through the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/datatype-numeric.html#datatype-serial BIGERIAL is a shortcut to define a type and a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently looking for a way in PostgreSQL where I can, for a
> given table, limit the number of valid foreign keys available by
> defining a condition.

**You can't do that.**

Foreign key constrains enforce referential integrity based on uniqueness, e.g. "table_a.id == table_b.a_id". You can't filter on overlapping date-ranges or anything like that.

I can think of fundamentally one way of doing what you are asking for: **Triggers***

It's not too complicated, you add "BEFORE INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE" triggers on each table that rejects all inserts/updates/deletes violating your rules.

If you can restructure your tables it becomes easier, you would just need two tables:

```
entry
  id
  type ("a", "b" ,"c")
  name ("cinit", etc.)

PK entry(id, type)

entry_version
  id
  entry_id
  type ("a", "b" ,"c")
  valid_period (tsrange)

PK entry_version(id)
FK entry_version(entry_id, type) -> entry(id, type)
```

now you only need a insert/update/delete trigger on entry_version that enforces the rules.

Things you might want to look into:

**EXCLUDE constraints** You could for example make sure you can't put two rows with overlapping date ranges in the same table.

**table partitions** You could have different partitions for each validity period or something. (is likely a dead end for you though).

Figure out some way of turning the date ranges into rows in a table and reference them with foreign keys.

*yes, there are also RULE:s but that's expert level

Answer (score -1):

I ended making a check constrain on both table A and table B
Where both checks this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lookup_filtering_check(
    intermediate_table regclass, 
    intermediate_table_column_name text, 
    timespan tsrange,
    lookup_value uuid,
    entity_id uuid,
    OUT result boolean
)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 
        FORMAT(
            'SELECT ('
                'NOT EXISTS('
                    'SELECT FROM %1$I '
                    'WHERE %1$I.valid && %3$L '
                    'AND %1$I.id = %5$L '
                    'AND %1$I.%2$I<> %4$L '
                ')'
            ')', 
            intermediate_table, 
            intermediate_table_column_name, 
            timespan, 
            lookup_value,
            entity_id)
   USING intermediate_table, timespan, lookup_value, id
   INTO result;

END
$$;
```

In table A and table B.

I do see some performance issues with this, since it has to check each row.

Comment: "PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table data other than the new or updated row being checked. While a CHECK constraint that violates this rule may appear to work in simple tests, it cannot guarantee that the database will not reach a state in which the constraint condition is false (due to subsequent changes of the other row(s) involved). This would cause a database dump and reload to fail. The reload could fail even when the complete database state is consistent with the constraint, due to rows not being loaded in an order that will satisfy the constraint.

Comment: Also, check constraints aren't evaluated when you delete rows so that is another way you could end up with invalid data.